# What happens when a Stored Procedure is created that contains other stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently running a CREATE PROC query to create a master stored procedure that runs 17 other stored procedures in turn. Each is sandwiched by an INSERT INTO statement to put a line into an audit table showing the datetime that the sproc was run before it, then after it an UPDATE statement that adds in the datetime the sproc finished running. For example;

```
------------------------------------------------------ STEP 1------------------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO [audit].[Marketing_Prefs_JobRun]
(
[Run_Step],
[Run_Start]
)
VALUES
(
1, -- Run_Step - int
GETDATE() -- Run_Start - datetime
)
GO

EXEC [dbo].[sp_Step_01_Refresh_Branch_4_Quotes]
GO

UPDATE [audit].[Marketing_Prefs_JobRun]
SET
[audit].[Marketing_Prefs_JobRun].[Run_End] = GETDATE()
WHERE [audit].[Marketing_Prefs_JobRun].[Run_Step] = 1
    AND (
            CAST([Run_Start] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                AND [Run_End] IS NULL
        )
GO
```

So there are 17 of the above inside this create proc statement.

Currently the CREATE PROC query is at 53 minutes and counting.

When running the basic query that executes these 17 stored procedures with PRINT statements showing the time each one finished, the entire batch takes about 1hr and 10 minutes (give or take) to run.

Is this CREATE PROC query to create my master stored procedure actually running through the code of all 17 stored procedures that will be called? I'm struggling to picture why it's taking such a long time to just create the procedure.

Comment: `CREATE PROC` should normally be very quick. What is the `CREATE` statement for your SP; you forgot to include it.

Comment: @Larnu it's literally just; CREATE PROC [audit].Marketing_Prefs_Run_Log
AS SET NOCOUNT ON and then 17 of those code blocks in the main question above.

Comment: The code above has batch separators in it (`GO`). If you were to have the code above in your SP, then your SP **only** would contain  `INSERT INTO [audit].[Marketing_Prefs_JobRun]
(
[Run_Step],
[Run_Start]
)
VALUES
(
1, -- Run_Step - int
GETDATE() -- Run_Start - datetime
)`

Comment: Yep, I just realised that I should have taken those out when I turned the select statement version into a sproc. I've swapped them all out for ; and it create the sproc instantly. Schoolboy error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you are under the impression you can have batch separators (`GO`) in your stored procedure. This is not the case. As a result, when you are running `CREATE PROC [audit].Marketing_Prefs_Run_Log AS SET NOCOUNT ON` prior to the SQL above, the first batch ends after the first `INSERT` statement. After that, all of your remaining SQL is run.

As a simple example:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE sample_tbl (ID int);
GO

CREATE PROC sample_sp AS

    INSERT INTO sample_tbl
    VALUES (1);
    GO
    INSERT INTO sample_tbl
    VALUES (2);
--GO --Commented out as we're already out of the SP CREATE batch.
--If you removed the first GO, then you'd need to uncomment this one so
--that the following statements are put inside the SP.
SELECT *
FROM sample_tbl; --Note the value 2 is in there

EXEC sample_sp;

SELECT *
FROM sample_tbl; --note the values are 2,1
GO

DROP TABLE sample_tbl;
```

You'll need to remove your `GO` operators to include the full statement in your SP.